# Simple and straightforward proof of Runge's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

As the question states, is there a simple and straightforward proof of Runge's approximation Theorem?
It seems that everywhere I look there are a bunch of lemmas that are first proved.

Is there a direct, non lemma involved proof which is accessible to a beginner?

Comment: I don't think that one can find a simpler proof than the one included in Sarason's Complex Analysis textbook. The separation lemma is not used to make things easier, it is the whole essence of Runge's theorem.

Comment: well what do you think about this: http://self.gutenberg.org/articles/Runge%27s_theorem

Comment: it states the separation lemma first